# How do I make a search bar with a filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried making a product filter but I made one but there was one problem. I wanted to click the items to redirect to another page but I tried coding hundreds of times but it was hopeless. So what I am asking from you is to build a product filter with a search bar. I hope you can help me. Please Help me! I need you! I hope that this isn't to much of a challenge.

Comment: Definitely not too much of a challenge. Also, what is the problem here? Clicking the items or filtering them? Also, this is not how you post here. You need to add relevant code as [mre] and describe what's happening, where exactly you're stuck, etc. You also need to have exhausted all other available resource (like Google) because SO is a last resort.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what language you are using. so assuming you are getting your product from some APIs . here an example for that.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "make": "Gibson",
        "model": "Les Paul",
        "type": "Electric",
        "price": "$3,000",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/LPST5HTHDCH-medium.jpg?9782bd",
    "url":"https://google.com"
    },
    {
        "make": "Gibson",
        "model": "SG",
        "type": "Electric",
        "price": "$1,500",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/SGSEBCH-medium.jpg?e69cfe",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    
    },
    {
        "make": "Fender",
        "model": "Telecaster",
        "type": "Electric",
        "price": "$2,000",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/TelePLMPHB-medium.jpg?28e48b",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    },
    {
        "make": "Fender",
        "model": "Stratocaster",
        "type": "Electric",
        "price": "$2,000",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/StratAMM3SB2-medium.jpg?dfd0a9",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    },
    {
        "make": "Gretsch",
        "model": "White Falcon",
        "type": "Electric",
        "price": "$5,000",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/G613655GE-medium.jpg?9bfb0e",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    },
    {
        "make": "Paul Reed Smith",
        "model": "Custom 24",
        "type": "Electric",
        "price": "$5,000",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/HBII10BGWB-medium.jpg?982763",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    },
    {
        "make": "Gibson",
        "model": "Hummingbird",
        "type": "Acoustic",
        "price": "$2,500",
        "image": "http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/120/SSHBHCNP-medium.jpg?11fbea",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    }
];

var products = "",
    makes = "",
    models = "",
    types = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var make = data[i].make,
        model = data[i].model,
        type = data[i].type,
        price = data[i].price,
        url = data[i].url,
        rawPrice = price.replace("$",""),
        rawPrice = parseInt(rawPrice.replace(",","")),
        image = data[i].image;
    
    //create product cards
    products += "<div class='col-sm-4 product' data-make='" + make + "' data-model='" + model + "' data-type='" + type + "' data-price='" + rawPrice + "'><div class='product-inner text-center'><a href='"+url+"'><img src='" + image + "'></a><br />Make: " + make + "<br />Model: " + model + "<br />Type: " + type + "<br />Price: " + price + "</div></div>";
    
    //create dropdown of makes
    if (makes.indexOf("<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + "</option>") == -1) {
        makes += "<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + "</option>";
    }
    
    //create dropdown of models
    if (models.indexOf("<option value='" + model+"'>" + model + "</option>") == -1) {
        models += "<option value='" + model + "'>" + model + "</option>";
    }
    
    //create dropdown of types
    if (types.indexOf("<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + "</option>") == -1) {
        types += "<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + "</option>";
    }
}

$("#products").html(products);
$(".filter-make").append(makes);
$(".filter-model").append(models);
$(".filter-type").append(types);

var filtersObject = {};

//on filter change
$(".filter").on("change",function() {
    var filterName = $(this).data("filter"),
        filterVal = $(this).val();
    
    if (filterVal == "") {
        delete filtersObject[filterName];
    } else {
        filtersObject[filterName] = filterVal;
    }
    
    var filters = "";
    
    for (var key in filtersObject) {
        if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            filters += "[data-"+key+"='"+filtersObject[key]+"']";
        }
    }
    
    if (filters == "") {
        $(".product").show();
    } else {
        $(".product").hide();
        $(".product").hide().filter(filters).show();
    }
});

//on search form submit
$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = $("#search-form input").val().toLowerCase();

    $(".product").hide();
    $(".product").each(function() {
        var make = $(this).data("make").toLowerCase(),
            model = $(this).data("model").toLowerCase(),
            type = $(this).data("type").toLowerCase();

        if (make.indexOf(query) > -1 || model.indexOf(query) > -1 || type.indexOf(query) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.product {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.product-inner {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    padding: 10px;
}
.product img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="search">
        <form id="search-form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="filter">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <select data-filter="make" class="filter-make filter form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Make</option>
                    <option value="">Show All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <select data-filter="model" class="filter-model filter form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Model</option>
                    <option value="">Show All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <select data-filter="type" class="filter-type filter form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Type</option>
                    <option value="">Show All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <select data-filter="price" class="filter-price filter form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Price Range</option>
                    <option value="">Show All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="products">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't really what I was looking for. It would be nice if you could click the items which redirect you to another webpage.

Comment: Click on products ?

Comment: i can add that if you want

Comment: Year please that World be great!

Comment: updated my answer with onclick redirection.

Comment: @TheDuo Since when do we start to write free code here? We help with code they have written but stackoverflow is not a free coding service.